# Adding methods to req?

Tags: node.js, express

librarys like express-validation and passport add methods to the req-variable, like `req.assert` and `req.user`. I know I can do this from inside a route:

```
app.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
   req.foo = bar;
   next();
}
```

But how can I do it from a library or external module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short:** You expose a handler function which your consumers will need to [`app.use()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use).

Here's the general approach. Consider the following module:

```
module.exports = function myExtension() {
  return function myExtensionHandler(req, res, next) {
    // This is called for every request - you can extend req or res here
    req.myFun = myFun

    // Make sure to call next() in order to continue the
    // chain of handlers
    return next()
  }
}

function myFun() {
  // My magic function
}
```

Now, from a consumer perspective:

```
const express = require('express')
const myExtension = require('my-extension')
const app = express()

// Here you tell Express to use your extension for incoming requests
app.use(myExtension())
// ...
```